# Update Local State when Creating and Deleting Associations in Apollo Client

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I have objects of type `student` and `team` in my schema and a table `student_team` that keeps records of their relationships.
To manage these I use the following calls:

```
// to add a student team relationship
mutation CreateStudentTeam($studentId: UUID!, $teamId: UUID!) {
  createStudentTeam(
    input: { studentTeam: { studentId: $studentId, teamId: $teamId } }
  ) {
    student {
      id
    }
    team {
      id
    }
  }
}

// to remove a student team relationship
mutation DeleteStudentTeam($studentId: UUID!, $teamId: UUID!) {
  deleteStudentTeamByStudentIdAndTeamId(input: {studentId:$studentId, teamId:$teamId}) {
    student {
      id
    }
    team {
      id
    }
  }
}

// to view teams with students
query Teams {
    teams {
      nodes {
        id
        name
        students {
          nodes {
            id
            fullName
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

My application presents data based on these relationships as listings.
A team might be presented with a listing of students.
I'm a bit confused about how to update the local state after making these calls.
Would the best thing to do to just redo the fetch for the data with the Teams query?
I'd love to know how best to do it with the Apollo Link State.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it manually using `update` prop passed:

```
graphql(YourMutation, {
  options: {
    update: (cache, result) => {
      const query = TeamsQuery
      const currentQueryData = cache.readQuery({query})
      const updatedData = //change your data regarding of the mutation
      cache.writeQuery({query, data: graphql updatedData })
    }
  }
}
```

also have a look at [this part](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/features/caching.html#writequery-and-writefragment) of the docs